# Golang learning, via tutorial. Pong game, ball bounces back and forth in the middle of the screen

Tags: go

I'm learning Go though Jack Mott's Games with Go on Youtube. Been solving my own issues so far, but this one has me struggling. The ball in the pong game bounces back and forth in the center of the screen. The offending area:

```
if int(ball.x) < int(rightPaddle.x)+rightPaddle.w/2 {
        if int(ball.y) > int(rightPaddle.y) - rightPaddle.h/2 && int(ball.y) < int(rightPaddle.y) +rightPaddle.h/2 {
            ball.xv = -ball.xv

        }
    }
```

(from the // START PADDLE section)

Is identical to the line above it for the leftPaddle. When this is commented out it works fine.

Can someone please take a look? I thought maybe it was the ball function, but it's identical to the video. I've gone up and down each line via the video but cannot seem to solve the issue.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"

"github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl"
)

const winWidth, winHeight int = 800, 600

type color struct {
    r, g, b byte
}

type pos struct {
    x,y float32
}


// BEGIN BALL

type ball struct {
    pos
    radius  int
    xv  float32
    yv  float32
    color   color
}
// DRAW BALL
func (ball *ball) draw(pixels []byte) {
    for y := -ball.radius; y < ball.radius; y++ {
        for x := -ball.radius; x < ball.radius; x++ {
            if x*x+y*y < ball.radius*ball.radius {
                setPixel(int(ball.x)+x, int(ball.y)+y, ball.color, pixels)
            }
        }
    }

}

func (ball *ball) update(leftPaddle *paddle, rightPaddle *paddle) {
    ball.x += ball.xv
    ball.y += ball.yv

    if int(ball.y)-ball.radius < 0 || int(ball.y)+ball.radius > winHeight {
        ball.yv = -ball.yv
    }
    if ball.x < 0 || int(ball.x) > winWidth {
        ball.x = 300
        ball.y = 300
    }
    if int(ball.x) < int(leftPaddle.x)+leftPaddle.w/2 {
        if int(ball.y) > int(leftPaddle.y) - leftPaddle.h/2 && int(ball.y) < int(leftPaddle.y) +leftPaddle.h/2 {
            ball.xv = -ball.xv

        }
    }

    if int(ball.x) < int(rightPaddle.x)+rightPaddle.w/2 {
        if int(ball.y) > int(rightPaddle.y) - rightPaddle.h/2 && int(ball.y) < int(rightPaddle.y) +rightPaddle.h/2 {
            ball.xv = -ball.xv

        }
    }
}

// END BALL
//********************************************************
// START PADDLE

type paddle struct {
    pos
    w       int
    h       int
    color   color

}

func (paddle *paddle) draw(pixels []byte) {
    startX := int(paddle.x) - paddle.w/2
    startY := int(paddle.y) - paddle.h/2

    for y := 0; y < paddle.h; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < paddle.w; x++ {
            setPixel(startX+x, startY+y, paddle.color, pixels)
        }
    }
}

func (paddle *paddle) update(keyState []uint8) {
    if keyState[sdl.SCANCODE_UP] != 0 {
        paddle.y--
    }
    if keyState[sdl.SCANCODE_DOWN] != 0 {
        paddle.y++
    }

}

// Player 2 Computer

func (paddle *paddle) aiUpdate(ball *ball) {
    paddle.y =  ball.y
}
// CLEAR PIXELS SO NO GHOSTING
func clear(pixels []byte) {
    for i := range pixels {
        pixels[i] = 0
    }
}

// END PADDLE

func setPixel(x, y int, c color, pixels []byte) {
    index := (y*winWidth + x) * 4

    if index < len(pixels)-4 && index >= 0 {
        pixels[index] = c.r
        pixels[index+1] = c.g
        pixels[index+2] = c.b
    }

}

func main() {

    // Added after EP06 to address macosx issues
    err := sdl.Init(sdl.INIT_EVERYTHING)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer sdl.Quit()

    window, err := sdl.CreateWindow("Testing SDL2", sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        int32(winWidth), int32(winHeight), sdl.WINDOW_SHOWN)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer window.Destroy()

    renderer, err := sdl.CreateRenderer(window, -1, sdl.RENDERER_ACCELERATED)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer renderer.Destroy()

    tex, err := renderer.CreateTexture(sdl.PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888, sdl.TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, int32(winWidth), int32(winHeight))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer tex.Destroy()

    pixels := make([]byte, winWidth*winHeight*4)

    tex.Update(nil, pixels, winWidth*4)
    renderer.Copy(tex, nil, nil)
    renderer.Present()

    player1 := paddle{pos{50,100},20, 100, color{255, 255, 255}}
    player2 := paddle{pos{float32(winWidth) - 50,100},20, 100, color{255, 255, 255}}
    ball := ball{pos{300, 300}, 20,4,4, color{255, 255, 255}}

    keyState := sdl.GetKeyboardState()

    // Changd after EP 06 to address MacOSX
    // OSX requires that you consume events for windows to open and work properly
    for {
        for event := sdl.PollEvent(); event != nil; event = sdl.PollEvent() {
            switch event.(type) {
            case *sdl.QuitEvent:
                return
            }
        }

        clear(pixels)

        player1.update(keyState)
        player2.aiUpdate(&ball)
        ball.update(&player1, &player2)

        player1.draw(pixels)
        player2.draw(pixels)
        ball.draw(pixels)


        tex.Update(nil, pixels, winWidth*4)
        renderer.Copy(tex, nil, nil)
        renderer.Present()

        sdl.Delay(16)
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you need `>` rather than `<` i.e. `if int(ball.x) > int(rightPaddle.x)+rightPaddle.w/2 {` (from the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RAwgmLjdCs&feature=youtu.be&t=3030))

Comment: Thank you very much. And I went over those lives several times, and even ran them through a comparison program.

Appreciate you.

Comment: No worries - have added an answer so others can see this is solved.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments it looks like you need `>` rather than `<` i.e.

`if int(ball.x) > int(rightPaddle.x)+rightPaddle.w/2 {`

([from the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RAwgmLjdCs&feature=youtu.be&t=3030))